# R output each data frame by a list of data

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list of data and I want to sort them out by their name into individual data frame.

list:

```
[1]
 Name Year Wage
 John 2000 500
 Paul 2000 600
 Peter 2000 800
 Mary 2000 700
 Kai 2000 800
 [2]
 Name Year Wage
 John 2005 600
 Paul 2005 700
 Peter 2005 1000
 Mary 2005 750
 Kai 2005 850
 [3]
 Name Year Wage
 John 2010 1600
 Paul 2010 900
 Peter 2010 1200
 Mary 2010 950
 Kai 2010 950
[n]
 Name Year Wage
 John 2011 1800
 Paul 2011 1000
 Peter 2011 1600
 Mary 2011 850
 Kai 2011 1050
```

Desired data frame 1:

```
Name Year Wage
John 2000 500 
John 2005 600
John 2010 1600
John 2011 1800
```

Desired data frame 2:

```
Name Year Wage
Paul 2000 600
Paul 2005 700
Paul 2010 900
Paul 2011 1000
```

and every name has its own .csv output.

I tried

```
listy <- list.files(path = "./",pattern = "*_output.csv", full.names = FALSE,recursive = TRUE)
lapply(listy, read.csv)
```

Then I have no idea how to continue. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @akrun thanks, but would you mind to further elaborate because I don't know what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `rbind` the `list` of `data.frame`s into a single dataset and then do the `split`

```
library(dplyr)
lstN <- bind_rows(lst) %>%
                split(., .$Name)
lapply(names(lstN), function(nm) write.csv(lstN[[nm]], paste0(nm, ".csv"),
     row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
```

#### data

```
lst <- lapply(listy, read.csv, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Warning Messages : In bind_rows_(x, .id) : Unequal factor levels: coercing to character comes up. and Can I write csv out one by one?

Comment: @kachunchung  That warning is just a friendly warning.  If you have read it with `lst <- lapply(listy, read.csv, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`, there will not be any warnings

Comment: @kachunchung  Updated the post with the `write.csv` step